# Inverse of a correlation matrix when all the correlations are equal

Tags: matrices

Let's have variables that multivariate normally distributed and have the same correlation among each other (different variance). Can we analytically derive the inverse of the correlation/covariance matrix?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If the $n\times n$ correlation matrix has value $1$ on the diagonal and value $\rho$ off the diagonal, then it can be written
$$(1-\rho)I + \rho y y^T \tag1$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $y$ is a column vector of all ones. As long as $\rho$ is neither one nor $-\frac1{n-1}$, the matrix (1) has an inverse and can be inverted via the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), which gives the inverse of any matrix of the form
$$A + uv^T$$
where $A$ is invertible and $u$ and $v$ are column vectors.